# Max sum of elements in list

Tags: python

I have a list of numbers. I need to choose a number from it, change its' sign, then take the total sum of the list, repeat if it does not produce the maximum sum.

Take [5, -6, 2, -9] for example
change 5 to -5 The sum is -18 which is not the maximum
Change -9 to 9 The sum is 10 which is the maximum

```
lst = [5, -6, 2, -9]

for i in range(len(lst)):
    lst[i] *= -1
    print (sum(lst))
```

this gives me all list multiplying by -1, I don't need that

```
import random

test_list = [5, -6, 2, 9]
random_num = random.choice(test_list)
random_num *=-1
print (random_num)
```

this gives me a random number with a reverse sign and then I don't know how to find the sum of the list

I'm stuck :/ maybe someone has any ideas?

Comment: More seems like a LeetCode problem. O(n^2) is pretty straight forward, every time you print the sum, change the lst[i] back. If you want O(n) solution, calculate the sum first, then update the sum for each index, then find the maximum sum.

Comment: It's also not necessary to recalculate the sum. When you change the sign of `l[i]`, the result is to subtract `2 * l[i]` from the sum.

Answer (score 0):

O(n^2)

```py
lst = [5, -6, 2, -9]
sums = []

for i in range(len(lst)):

    lst[i] *= -1

    sums.append(sum(lst))

    lst[i] *= -1

print(max(sums))
```

O(n)

```py
lst = [5, -6, 2, -9]

lst_sum = sum(lst)
max_sum = float('-inf')

for i in range(len(lst)):
    max_sum = max(max_sum, lst_sum - 2 * lst[i])

print(max_sum)
```

Put in a little more brain cells and we can actually:

```
lst = [5, -6, 2, -9]

max_sum = sum(lst) - 2 * min(lst)

print(max_sum)
```

Comment: Or just `lst_sum - 2 * min_val`